# useEffect overriding the state instead of appending the values while making firestore calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
    
     const getDataFromFirebase = async () => {
         let response = await firestore.collection('someDatabase').get()
         response.forEach(item => setData([...data, item.data().name]))
         
     }
    
    useEffect(() => {
       getDataFromFirebase()
    },[])
```

data is being overridden with the latest value instead of adding all the values to the array.

Comment: item.data() is a function?

Comment: `data` is being used inside the useEffect. Please put it in the dependency array. Although that may cause an infinite loop...

Answer (score 3):

The reason is time taken to add item is very less thats why before reflecting, it got override. You have to use prevState in setData . Try this:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const getDataFromFirebase = async () => {
let response = await firestore.collection('someDatabase').get()
response.forEach(item => setData(prevState => ([
    ...prevState, item.data().name])
  );
}
useEffect(() => {
  getDataFromFirebase()
  },[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback in `setData`

```
setData(prevState => ([
    ...prevState, item.data().name
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let response = await firestore.collection('someDatabase').get()
response.forEach(item => setData([...data, item.data().name]))
```

I'm not familiar with `firestore`, but that promise will be resolved once, and you should do something like this instead:

```
const dataToAdd = response.map(item => item.data().name)
setData(prevState => ([...prevState, ...dataToAdd])
```

You are rerending component each time the `setData` is being called and you shouldn't do it in a synced loop.

`prevState` is necessary here because you are working in an asynchronous function. In theory, it should work without it after using a solution with `dataToAdd` if you don't change the state anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

try this fire setState once but build the array before :

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
    
 const getDataFromFirebase = async () => {
    let response = await firestore.collection('someDatabase').get()
    const d = response.map(item=> item.data().name)
    setData(d)  
  }
    
 useEffect(() => {
       getDataFromFirebase()
 },[])
```

firing `setData` multiple times will cause multiple rerenders so here it's fire once.

Comment: Tried this way, except I changed the map to forEach and it worked fine. But I want to know why my earlier version is not working

Comment: `map` should have return value and `foreach` no return needed. and for why your previous code not working because react update state asynchronously, so when you fire `setData([...data, item.data().name])` maybe data is not set yet by react that why it's still empty

Comment: @adel OP asked for why data is not appending, this solution is not answering that. The above code will not append to existing data array. Its just overwrites it.

Comment: @phantomCode oh yes you are  right , but for the code above `getDataFromFirebase ` is only fired one which is on mount and the default state is  empty array so there is nothing to override. and we want want to fire  to append to state elsewhere we can use `setState` callback like this :  setData(currentState=>[...currenState,..d])

Answer (score 0):

In your code below the value of data will be always `[]` even if you change the data later.

```
const getDataFromFirebase = async () => {
         let response = await firestore.collection('someDatabase').get()
         response.forEach(item => setData([...data, item.data().name]))
         
     }
```

This is what docs say about it

> Mutations, subscriptions, timers, logging, and other side effects are
> not allowed inside the main body of a function component (referred to
> as React’s render phase). Doing so will lead to confusing bugs and
> inconsistencies in the UI.

Its not a good idea to call setData in each loop. Populate an array and pass it to `setData` once loop is complete.

```
     const getDataFromFirebase = async () => {
         let response = await firestore.collection('someDatabase').get();
         let newData = [];
         response.forEach(item => newData.push(item.data().name));

         // now set the new data
         setData(prevData=> ([...prevData, ...newData]));
         
         // or you can use Array.concat
         // setData(prevData=> (prevData.concat(newData)));
     }
```

Comment: why value of data will be always [], please clarify your answer before posting !

Comment: Because the function will not listen for any change in data. If we need to get the latest data use the updater function which has access to previous data. Or listen to change in data using `useEffect` and provide `data` in the dependency array. Read docs before commenting!

Comment: @adel `data` will not have the updated value unless u use `useEffect`, that how closures works, plz refresh basics

Comment: @ phantomCoder lol i know react better than you, and i am just asking him to clarify the answer for other people to understand. for the problem is that react update state asynchronously that why data will not be updated immediately.

Comment: @adel being asynchronous is not the reason why data is not updated. What you said is correct for `setState` but not for `useState`. `data` will still have the initial data even if you wait for 1 hr. We have updater function and useEffect for a reason.