# React - How to stop slow useEffect overriding state of fast useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component:

```
   function QueryError({ query }) {
      const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    
      async function updateVisible(query) {
        if (await checkQuery(query)) {
          setVisible(true);
        } else {
          setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      
      useEffect(() => {
        updateVisible(query);
      }, [query]);
    
      return (visible ? <Error error="checkQuery returned true" /> : null);
   }
```

The query originates from a text input. The issue arises when someone enters a slow query and follows it with a fast one immediately after. Once the slow query on the old component completes, it inadvertently overwrites the `visible` status on the new one. Consequently, the error message is displayed when it shouldn't be.

In the answers to this question [useEffect overriding the state instead of appending the values while making firestore calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207294/useeffect-overriding-the-state-instead-of-appending-the-values-while-making-fire), they say do `setData(prevState => newState).` But this only helps when the new state depends on the previous state, and mine doesn't.

Also, I tried it without useEffect and useState, just doing `const visible = updateVisible(query),` but then the visible never changed.

Comment: Show the parent component from where the query prop comes

Comment: Sounds like you need to cancel whatever async process runs for each query when they change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue you're facing is related to the asynchronous nature of `updateVisible` and how it affects the visibility state of your component when handling a fast query immediately after a slow one. To address this issue, you can maintain a reference to the query in your component, allowing you to disregard the result of a previous asynchronous operation when it's no longer relevant.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function QueryError({ query }) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const queryRef = useRef(null);

  async function updateVisible(query) {
    const currentQuery = query; // Store the current query locally.
    const result = await checkQuery(currentQuery);

    // Only update the state if the query matches the current query reference.
    if (currentQuery === queryRef.current) {
      setVisible(result);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    queryRef.current = query; // Update the query reference.
    updateVisible(query);

    return () => {
      // Reset the query reference when the component unmounts.
      queryRef.current = null;
    };
  }, [query]);

  return query ? <Error error="checkQuery returned true" /> : null;
}
```